# Database Query executes even though row hasn't been created yet

Tags: php

I can't understand why `mysqli_query` returns true on an operation where one of the fields doesn't exist. I am trying to `UPDATE` a field when the field `run_id` matches the variable `$id`. However, when `$id` isn't set, the echo inside the if statement executes. Would really appreciate your thoughts on this phenomenon.

```
function sumMiles($id,$runnerRow,$weekArray,$cnn){
    //Calculate cumulative miles per week for every runner
    $weekMiles=0; //total miles per week
    foreach($weekArray as $weekday)
        {
            $weekMiles+=$runnerRow[$weekday];
        }
        $addMiles = "UPDATE run SET weekly_total = {$weekMiles} WHERE run_id=$id";//add weekly total into the database's run table 
        if (mysqli_query($cnn,$addMiles)){
            echo "Your weekly total has been updated";
            return $weekMiles;
        }
        else {echo "Your weekly total could not be updated";}
    }
```

I am calling this function like so:

```
$weekMiles = sumMiles($id,$dailyMileage,$weekArray,$cnn);
```

Comment: sorry, just removed

Comment: What do you mean by `the query successfully executes`? `weekly_total ` changed in the DB table?

Comment: i meant that the echo inside the if statement executed. will edit my question

Comment: `mysqli_query('UPDATE ...')` may return `TRUE` even it has not done any actual change to the values in DB table.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the line doens't exist will not generate any exception at the database.

Verify the existence of the line first before run your update

```
  select count(1) from  run WHERE run_id=$id
```

**EDIT**

You need to check if the `Count(1)` is bigger than 0

```
$query = "SELECT count(1) from run WHERE run_id=$id"; 
if (mysqli_query($cnn,$query)>0){ 
 $addMiles = "UPDATE run SET weekly_total = {$weekMiles} WHERE run_id=$id"; 
 echo "updated"; 
}
```

Comment: I tried   `$query = "SELECT count(1) from  run WHERE run_id=$id";
  if (mysqli_query($cnn,$query)){
   $addMiles = "UPDATE run SET weekly_total = {$weekMiles} WHERE run_id=$id";
   echo "updated";
  }` but the query still returned TRUE